# How to set the value of each bar on top of the column graph in highchart

Tags: r, highcharts

I have a dataframe like the belowing one and i want to plot a column graph with the value of the variation on top of each column which must be similar to the richbourse [site](https://www.richbourse.com/common/variation/index) graph

[image: 2]

```
qt <- data.frame(Symbole = c("STAC", "NEIC", "SAFC", "FTSC", "SCRC",
                         "PALC", "ABJC", "SOGC", "SNTS", "TTLC", "SLBC", "UNXC", "SICC",
                         "CBIBF", "BOABF", "SMBC", "BNBC", "BOAB", "CABC", "CFAC", "ECOC",
                         "ETIT", "NSBC", "NTLC", "ONTBF", "SDCC", "SEMC", "SGBC", "SHEC",
                         "SVOC", "TTLS", "TTRC", "UNLC", "STBC", "SPHC", "ORGT", "BOAN",
                         "BOAC", "SDSC", "BOAM", "SIBC", "CIEC", "BOAS", "BICC", "SIVC",
                         "PRSC"),
             `Cours clôture (FCFA)` = c(1440, 740, 850, 1700, 920,7505, 1600, 5000,
                                        14150, 2245, 165000, 2055, 4865, 9750, 6140,
                                        7080, 2200, 5650, 1190, 1160, 4675, 23, 5755,
                                        5275, 4195, 4450,735, 11200, 980, 0, 2050, 0,
                                        0, 5850, 5100, 3905, 5145, 5310, 2500, 1380,
                                        3985, 2150, 2500, 5855, 775, 4715),
             `Variation(%)` = c(7.29,7.25, 6.51, 2.41, 2.17, 1.96, 1.54, 1.41, 0.71,
                                0.67, 0.61, 0.48,0.31, 0.3, 0.16, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, -0.08, -0.38,
                                -0.64, -0.78, -0.94, -0.97, -1.09,-1.27, -2.33,
                                -2.72, -6.91, -7.1, -7.29),
             position = c("Up","Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up",
                          "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up",
                          "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Up", "Down",
                          "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down",
                          "Down", "Down", "Down", "Down"))
```

This is what i try

````
library(highcharter)
hchart(qt, type = 'bar', hcaes(x = Symbole, y = `Variation(%)`,group = position ))%>%
  hc_colors(colors = c("red", 'green'))```
````

My graphs i obtain are the general graph [image: 3] ,
when i click on top [image: 4] and when i click on Flop [image: 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best one is

```
qt%>%hchart('column', name = c('Flop', 'Top'),
            hcaes(x = Symbole, y = `Variation(%)`,
                  group = position))%>%
    hc_plotOptions(series = list(
        borderWidth= 0,
        dataLabels = list(
            enabled = TRUE,
            color = "black",
            format = '{point.y:.1f}'
        )))%>%
    hc_colors(colors = c("red", 'green'))
```

[image: Flop and top]

Comment: Now How can i turn the code so that the top must come first? I have try several options with adequate result as the first image i sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataLabels options [dataLabels.verticalAlign](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels.verticalAlign) and [dataLabels.y](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels.y) to set position to bottom or top.

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: 'white',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 20
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rn35bud0/2/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels.verticalAlign,

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels.y

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. How to use the plotOptions as R code not a jscode? Thanks once again.